# loop through collection laravel with when()

Tags: laravel, if-statement, query-builder

I am creating a group stage tourney results page. I have converted wins to 3, l's 0, and tie's 1. The tie breaker (something I did not create) is the head-to-head records within the group. So I need a query that utilizes this variable:

```
        $grouphhomescores= PointData::selectRaw('team, sum((win)+(loss)+ 
   (tie)) as pointTotal')
   ->where('stage', 'group')
   ->where('stageSeries', 'H')
   ->where('ar', $id)->groupBy('team')
   ->orderBy('pointTotal', 'desc')
   ->distinct()->get();
```

But includes a when() (I believe) for when $grouphhomescores=$grouphhomescores that can somehow calculate the head v head record and determine which outcome yields the most points.

Comment: Maybe if I OrderBy PointTotal then OrderBy other conditions, how is that achieved?

Comment: You can do multiple order by `->orderBy('pointTotal', 'desc')->orderBy('something_else', 'desc')`

Comment: How can I orderBy at a certain conditio? Such as 'code' orderBy('pointTotal', 'desc').-> if pointTotal=pointTotal (orderBy, 'homeScore')'code'

Comment: Order by is a sort priority, if you do `->orderBy('pointTotal', 'desc')->orderBy('homeScore','desc')` then the first sorting is done by points total and then if points total are equal the sorting is done by home score.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.